Unity Whiteboard Feature Performance Issues on Interactive Flat Panels
I'm developing a Unity application for Interactive Flat Panels (smartboards) used in schools and offices. We've implemented a whiteboard feature using various assets from the Unity Asset Store. However, we're experiencing significant performance issues:

Severe frame rate drops
The whiteboard feature is nearly unusable due to poor performance

Technical details:

Unity version: 2022.3.10f1
Target platform: Android
Hardware: Interactive Flat Panels (smartboards)
Assets used: XD Paint

What we've tried:

Tried tweaking settings in XD paint
tried custom renderer

Questions:

What are some common causes of performance issues in Unity-based whiteboard applications?
Are there any specific optimization techniques for drawing/rendering in Unity that could help our situation?
Are there any recommended assets or approaches for creating high-performance whiteboard features in Unity, especially for touch-based interfaces?

Any insights, suggestions, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Sathiya

You need the hardware specification of these "whiteboard" devices. Unclear if they are e-ink/e-paper based, low refresh LED panels, weak CPU or something else. Find out what is device screen resolution and if there is a device screen bandwidth limit for rendering. If technical details are unavailable, start by trying to play a small size (width x height) known video file with a native Android app and increase the video file until performance is no longer acceptable.

Didn't see any "white boards" with more than 4GB RAM. That would be a concern to me using Unity. Where do you do the development? On the white board? What can a white board do that a touch panel can't? I run UWP apps on my Surface Go (8GB); but UWP has a visual layer "guaranteed" to run at 60 FPS; for "independent" animations.

@MorrisonChang Sorry for the late response. The panel uses Mali G52 GPU having a resolution of  3840（H）× 2160（V). What is the device screen bandwidth limit? How to check that?

@GerrySchmitz Sorry for the late response. Whiteboard is a software feature we use within our app. It is used to write on an IFP panel. Teh use case is such that we display 3D models and presenter can use whiteboard markers to annotate on the 3D models.

I would try to find the CPU for that device. One link: https://www.notebookcheck.net/ARM-Mali-G52-MP2-GPU-Benchmarks-and-Specs.466940.0.html shows it to be a mid-range GPU that is 4K capable but it may be that the combined CPU+GPU can't do what you want. I would test with simpler touch based Unity samples to see perf. But I also found Unity 2021/2022 laggy/stuttering Android performance compared to Unity 2020 in this search so you may be better off in a Unity forum.

Thanks much @MorrisonChang, I will check these.
